# Why doesn't type on path in illustrator wrap around properly?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to get 'title goes here...' to wrap around the pink circle - the type is on a path with it being aligned centre.

However, at either end of the title it moves away from the pink circle rather than being tight to it like it is in the middle.

Why does it do this? How do I resolve it?

[image]

Comment: Probably you have a different circle for the type path, which is shifted a bit down (i mean centers of both circles are not aligned). Can you cross check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because either you have shifted the circle (on which text is typed) a bit down or its size has been affected, by mistake. In other words, both your pink circle and text circle are not concentric. You can see one such example in following GIF, when you move the text circle, it affects the text alignment to the curve.

[image]

To avoid this, make sure you don't move the circle individually. Move the entire group of artworks if you have to. If you want to resize the text circle alone, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (on Windows) while you resize it. That won't affect the circle center position and keep both circles concentric.

Another less likely issue could be that you're using some Envelop Distort (Warp) on the text.

Comment: Also i would like to point you can use a filled circele as a path for the text. TRick is to select path with direct selection arrow and reaply after adding a path. You can then addjust the distace of text with text offsets.

Comment: @joojaa sorry didn't get. did you mean we don't need two circles for fill and text? Can be done with same circle?

Comment: yes. you just have to color the circle again